# What is the canonical way to handle errors during Ajax-requests?

Tags: ajax, error-handling, jsf-2, glassfish-3, mojarra

For normal requests we can simple register an `<error-page>` in `web.xml`. However, this does not apply to Ajax-requests. By default errors during an Ajax-request will result in a little pop-window in the browser that shows the exception.

The main example I am struggling with is handling a `ViewExpiredException` in a uniform way. For standard requests, I redirect to a page that explains that the user is not logged in and provides a link to the login-page. I would like to do the same for Ajax-requests. There seem to be several ways:

1. I could write a javascript function that handles the error on the client-side and redirects to the error-page. I would then have to add this function *every `<f:ajax>`-tag on all pages* using the `onerror`-attribute. Is there a way to tell JSF that I want to have this javascript-function as the default error-handler for all `<f:ajax>`-tags?
2. I could use a custom exception-handler, as described in [this blog](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/edburns/archive/2009/09/03/dealing-gracefully-viewexpiredexception-jsf2). This seems to do what I want, but I wonder if it is overkill. Is there no simpler solution?

So my question is, how is this supposed to be solved? Which of the approaches I listed should be used? Is there another approach that I do not know of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`jsf.ajax.addOnError()`](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/jsdocs/symbols/jsf.ajax.html#.addOnError) to set the default error handler. E.g.

```js
jsf.ajax.addOnError(function(data) {
    alert(data.responseText);
});
```

See also chapter 13.3.6.2 of the [JSF2 spec](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr314/index.html). You can find all properties of `data` object in table 14-4 of the JSF2 spec.